# How to use DelegateCommand in ViewModelBase?

Tags: c#, oop, prism-6

I have a ViewModelBase that looks like the following:

```
public class ViewModelBase : BindableBase, INavigationAware, IActiveAware, IDockAware
    {
       public ViewModelBase() {SaveCommand = new DelegateCommand(OnSave, CanSave);}
        public DelegateCommand SaveCommand { get; set; }
       protected virtual void OnSave() { }
```

In my class I inherit from ViewModelBase like so:

```
public class FooViewVM : ViewModelBase
    {
      protected override async void OnSave() { await dto.Save(Foo); }
    }
```

When I press the Save button (located in a Ribbon in a different group), the command executes but the code does not run the FooViewVM, but stops at the virtual void in ViewModelBase.  I'm a little confused because I thought that the method in the VM would be executed (since it overrides the virtual method in the base). Do I have too many interfaces defined in the base classes?  Should I move the DelegateCommand(s) into each VM instead of inheriting?  And finally, I'd like to better understand why this isn't working like I expected.

Comment: What you are trying should work. I tried it myself, and it worked as expected. The only interface I do not implement in my base class is the `IDockAware`.

Comment: Perhaps it's just not using the `FooViewVM` class like you are expecting?